# Trying to parse XML file with <p> tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I have been trying to parse the contents of an XML file using PowerShell and have I have made some decent progress, but I ran into something I cant find an answer to. I hope someone can point me in the right direction or help me understand how to get the value of some content in my XML which is contained within some P tags. Here is an example of my XML file;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HVD version="2.0">
<Environment>
    <p name="Version">10</p>
    <p name="ID">258</p>
</Environment>
</HVD>
```

I can get the Name label in `<Environment>` to show up by using the following, but I cannot figure out how to get the values from the `<p>` tags themselves;

```bsh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content myFile.xml;
$xml.HVD.Environment;
```

Can anyone help out a beginner here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text between the tags (10 and 258) is thr innerText of the p tags. So you'll need to get the first/second element of the Environment tag and read it's innerText.

Comment: thanks, I tried using InnerText, but I couldn't figure out how to specify which tag to get the value from. 

this command just returns them all;
    $xml.HVD.Environment.innertext;

is there a way to specify which one I want the value from?

Comment: You also need to select which p tag like so: $xml.HVD.Environment.p[0].innerText

Comment: Hey, that's awesome, it worked (but you knew that)... Thank you so much @Cyphrags! Now I can make some real progress on my project.

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[xml]$xml = get-content myfile.xml
$Version=($xml.HVD.Environment.P | where Name -eq 'version')."#text"
$ID=($xml.HVD.Environment.P | where Name -eq 'ID')."#text"
```

or this

```
$Version=$xml.HVD.Environment.P[0]."#text";
$ID=$xml.HVD.Environment.P[1]."#text";
```

Comment: alternatives are always good. Much appreciated Esperento57 - thank you!